# my administrator account on win 8 home edition can not change date through a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry, policy

i have win 8 home edition (no local policy editor) on my pc if i tried to change my system date or time with a batch file i get the following message :

```
 a required priviledge is not held by the client
```

that means my administrator account doesnt have the enough privilege to change date through cmd or batch file

i know its easy to solve this issue if it was win 8 pro , because in this case i can change my account privilege through the local policy editor witch is not included in any windows home edition

also im running this batch file throw ms access database so i dont have the ability to  to run the batch file in a command prompt opened as Administrator

my question is : how to change my administrator privilege to be able to change system date in this case ?? using registry key or any other way

Comment: You need to run the batch file in a command prompt opened as Administrator. (On Windows 7, Win+R, type "command", right-click, choose "Run as Administrator"; not sure what the equivalent is on Win8.)

Comment: the problem is that im running this batch file throw ms access database so i dont have the ability to do that

Comment: That information should be included in your question so that people can see it, since it very relevant. Of course, that brings up the question "Why are you using a batch file in a command prompt to change the time from a Windows application (MSAccess), instead of using the Windows API?", not to mention "Why do you need to change the system time at all?"